# How do i add a countdown timer when the program begins?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I'm creating a game where a spaceship has to collide with planets that are orbiting the centre of the screen. I want there to be a certain time limit so these planets have to be destroyed within the time limit

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Timer` class if you want to delay the explosion, if that's what you were getting at:

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1); // delay: 5s
myTimer.addEventListener("timer", timerHandler);

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
    trace('my planet explodes');
}

function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {
    if (spaceship.hitTestObject(planet)) {
        myTimer.start();
    }
}
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
```

To learn more about [`Timer class`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can also create the timer at ADDED_TO_STAGE event, so, your timer will begin when the program stars.

```
public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // CREATE YOUR TIMER HERE
    }
```